# MNIST hand digits recognition task on Mac but not outputting the photos of the hand written numbers

Tags: python, keras, tensor, mnist, digits

I'm doing a MNIST hand digits recognition task on my Mac but it is not displaying the predicted value against the images and only gets up to accuary checks.

I'm using Spyder, on my mac. It seems to work perfectly fine on windows but not on my mac. By the way, I'm using the python (spyder) 3.7.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data() 
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)), 
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu), 
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

x_pred_value = np.argmax(model.predict(x_test),axis=1)

for i in range(7):
    print("\nThe following digit is a ",x_pred_value[i]) 
    plt.imshow(x_test[i])
plt.show()
```

I expect the code to give me an output of the photo and give a prediction using the line: "The following output is a..."

Also, these are the warning messages I got:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:435: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py:143: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Ra
2019-05-19 08:46:38.036080: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2019-05-19 08:46:38.036685: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:71] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 4. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
```

Comment: Can you please add the output snapshot or something like that?

Comment: And BTW, your warning messages have nothing to do with your output. They are just deprecation warnings.